# click link in dropdown menu closes dropdown doesn't go to link

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu

I am trying to create a responsive drop-down menu.  The menu works perfectly except for when you try to select one of the menu links.  Clicking a link closes the menu but doesn't open  the link you just stay on the current page.

My jquery to open the menu is:

```
$('.menu-button').click(function(){
     $('nav').addClass('active');
});
```

relevant css:

```
@media only screen and (max-width:760px) {
.active{
    text-align:center;
}

.active ul{
    border:1px solid #ccc;
    margin-top:40px;
    display:block;
    width:100%;
}

.active ul li {
    border:1px solid #ccc;
    margin:0;
    width:100%;
    height:40px;
    line-height:40px;
}
.active ul li a {
    display:block;
}

.active a:hover {
    background-color:#ecf1fc;
    color:#020202;
    top:0;
}
}
```

you can check out the site at [www.teal.indiancreekboulderingclub.com.](http://www.teal.indiancreekboulderingclub.com)

I am just learning jquery, so please keep the javascript explanations elementary. Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inspecting your CSS I noticed this:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 760px) {
    nav ul, nav:active ul {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

Change that to:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 760px) {
    nav ul {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

Your jQuery seems to be functioning fine. But you could change it to:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('.menu-button').click(function(){
        $('nav').toggleClass('active');
    });
});
```

This will allow users to show and hide the navigation.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to move the 'active' class to the ul tag instead of the nav tag.

***site.js***, change to:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('.menu-button').click(function(){
        $('nav ul').toggleClass('active');
    });
});
```

***style.css***, at line 296:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 760px) {

    ul.active {
        border:1px solid #ccc;
        margin-top:40px;
        display:block;
        width:100%;
        padding-left: 0;
        list-style: none;
    }

    ul.active li {
        border: 1px solid #ccc;
        margin:0;
        width: 100%;
        height:40px;
        line-height:40px;    
        border-left: 0;
        border-right: 0;
    }

    ul.active li a {
        display:block;
    }

    ul.active a:hover {
        background-color:#ecf1fc;
        color:#020202;
        top:0;
    }
}
```